# How to call JavaScript with Android 4.4 Webview?

Tags: android

I wanted to modify one input value in the html after loading the webpage. I prepared to do this by calling javascript function with the WebView. It worked well if I set the `android:targetSdkVersion` to 18. But once I set it to 19, it shows the value of the second url, even it's just the javascript calls. Here's test code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String mJSCall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (mJSCall != null) {
                    view.loadUrl(mJSCall);
                    mJSCall = null;
                }

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://wap.soso.com/?g_f=2405");
        String keyword = "My Keyword";
        mJSCall = "javascript:document.getElementById('keyword').value='"+keyword+"'";

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Could you tell me why it failed to call javascript function when `targetSdkVersion=19`? It seems that when the `onPageFinished` method is called the first url already refreshed sometimes, maybe that's why I could not modify the value in the html at that time.

So is there any right time to call javascript except the `onPageFinished`? I have struggled for the last day to find a reasonable solution. If anyone can help, please do. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could you tell me why it failed to call javascript function when targetSdkVersion=19?

[Use `evaluateJavascript()` instead](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29). `loadUrl()` always loads a new page on Android 4.4 with a target SDK version of 19+, instead of evaluating a `javascript:` URL in the context of the currently-loaded page as before.

Comment: I don't know why it failed to call javascript function when targetSdkVersion=19. I suppose that google has changed the behavior of the loadUrl method for Android 4.4. I will try to use evaluateJavascript() later. Thank you!

Comment: can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702036/webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-not-getting-called)